# Strange image orientation with all camera apps

Tags: camera, exif

I've just noticed that on my *Wileyfox Swift* there's something strange going on with image orientation:

- taking a landscape image, everything is fine: the resulting JPG is in landscape, and Exif has `Orientation:0` – as one would expect.
- taking a portrait image however also has `Orientation:0`, and the resulting JPG is in portrait – while on all my other devices, the JPG would remain landscape but have e.g. `Orientation:6` (rotate 270°) in its Exif.

I've tried with multiple camera apps, including the integrated one. Two other camera apps I use on other devices as well, where they work as expected.

What might go on here, and how to fix it up? I need it the "standard way" for post processing scripts etc. Though the results "look the same" in image viewers, the technical details/differences are relevant in my case, so I wish the Wileyfox to adhere to the standards :)

Comment: You've just made me google what the hell a Wileyfox Swift is. It looks good :) In seriousness, @Izzy (pinging just in case) This appears to be happening quite ofteh with different devices and cameras, like this one: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/issues/241

Comment: I don't see why it's a problem. The orientation EXIF field just tells you whether the actual geometry of the picture disagrees with the order of the pixels in the file. The phone isn't breaking any standard.

Comment: @DanHulme It might not be a problem for you – but it is for me. This is the first (and only) device dealing with it that way. All my post-processing relies on the fact that fotos are always stored landscape, and orientation is stored in the file's Exif data. So I want to know if there's a way to fix that. It might well be it's not breaking a standard (as there might be no standard explicitly defined) – but all other devices I know of (including cameras) dealing with it via Exif makes this an exception. And I don't want that exception :)

Comment: @DanBrown the issue you've linked is somehow different (talking about emulator and the preview shown wrong – I don't see any relation to Exif there). But thanks for the pointer: as the owner explicitly mentions the Swift, I may ping him for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you don't have any chance to make the image be in landscape mode when taken, if you don't have the source code of your ROM. But you can surely post-process it by yourself.

[Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) provides some helpful (and famous) utilities like `jhead` and `imagemagick`. It's possible to write shell scripts that rotate portrait images into landscape and add a "Rotation" in the EXIF to "rotate" it back.

Comment: I didn't ask about post-processing (of course I could check width & heights and then rotate + add exif rotation) – as commented on the question, I do some post-processing already, but I don't want an extra step for those basic stuff. So I want to know how to have the correct Exif info in there to start with, instead of having the photo "hard rotated" and correct that afterwards.

Comment: @Izzy If you have the source of the ROM you can surely tewak somewhere in `/system/lib`so the library provides the desired function.

Comment: As it's CyanogenOS, source should be available. But me not being a dev, I wouldn't know where to start even. I was hoping there might be some "hidden setting" one could tweak somewhere, either via some dialog or using `setprop` and friends. Nevertheless, thinking twice your proposal becomes intriguing: I could do the rotation in the after-after processing (after color correction and other editing) where I fix some other Exif-based stuff anyway – whenever the photo is stored as portrait, rotate it by 90° and update Exif accordingly. Not my first choice, but good enough. Will check, tnx.

Comment: OK, adjusted my workflow accordingly by rotating portrait images (identified by "height > width") after editing and updating Exif rotation accordingly (have a script adjusting the timestamps running then anyway, so there it went). Should work out (will see with the next batch), so I'm accepting the answer for now (thanks! Most obvious things come to mind last :). Though I'd still like to know how to fix the original issue (instead of having to work around it).